# Closed as duplicate but not actually answered

Tags: discussion

[How heavy is Mjölnir to Thor? To Capt America?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/244433/83542)

My question was closed as a duplicate.  A commenter had linked the supposed answer, but that has since been removed.  I had clearly stated that the other question did not answer my question.

Why was mine closed?

Comment: "A commenter had linked the supposed answer, but that has since been removed." - The "Does this answer your question?" comment is automated. It's posted automatically when someone votes to close your question as a duplicate, and is deleted automatically if/when the question is closed.

Comment: [I voted to leave open and removed it from the review queue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/174359), but more close-voters came later. It seems to me that you're right and the questions are related but not duplicates, however I think this meta post would be better received if you can explain *why* here, rather than just saying the other questions doesn't answer yours.

Comment: FWIW I think you've misunderstood or are putting too much thought into Mjolnir. Others can't move it because they aren't worthy; it's just handwaved with magic. Now if you're asking what it feels like to those that are worthy the duplicate seems to answer that question; [specifically this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18818/58193) goes into detail about it. Personally as it stands I'd vote to leave this closed unless you can explain _why_ (as mentioned above) the duplicate doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Just because you've "clearly stated that the other question did not answer my question" doesn't mean that it's not a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

I voted to closed it as a dupe because the [question that you're asking](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/244433/83542) (which basically boils down to "*What does the weight of Mjölnir feel like to those who're wielding it*" is largely a duplicate of another question that is extremely similar ([How much would Thor's hammer (Mjolnir) weigh?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18812/how-much-would-thors-hammer-mjolnir-weigh)).

While they do focus on slightly different *aspects* of Mjölnir's weight, that is to say, its *absolute* weight versus its *subjective* weight, I think we can be reasonably certain that if a canonical answer was found to one of the questions ("**in comic x, it's stated that Asgardian magic makes Mjölnir feel very light**") it would certainly be copied/pasted to the other question almost immediately. That in itself seems a pretty clear benchmark that the two questions are basically duplicates of each other.

On top of that, the other question already has [answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18818/58193) that address its absolute weight so unless you can express some reason to assume that the subjective weight is different, there's really no good reason to have a second question about it.

Comment: -1: The only answers to the canonical question which actually try to answer the supposed dupe are scored 0 or less, and don't seem to have much in the way of citations to support them. There's a rule requiring that canonicals have answers, and in this case, the canonical has no good answers which match the dupe. Until those answers actually exist, it's not a dupe by SE rules.

Comment: @Kevin maybe I’m misunderstanding the question slightly but how does [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18818/58193) at least not answer the question?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I don't see how you can possibly think that answer helps. It briefly acknowledges that the subjective-weight question exists and then doesn't answer it.

Comment: @Kevin It does say that "Marvel produced a trading card which specified Mjolnir's weight as 42.3 lbs" at the pretty end though, after going in-depth into several analysis of how much it can possibly weight.